# can a socket with the same local address be in two states at once 'LISTEN' and 'ESTABLISHED'

Tags: sockets, ssl, listen

I have a question about sockets where a socket gets in to a peculiar situation, it is both Listening and Established. I must add that I am working with SSL sockets. It is possible that the TLS handshake timed out and some how this got in to this state?

netstat output

```
tcp 0 0 XX.XX.xx.83.9999 XX.XX.xx.10.42146 ESTABLISHED --> socket in established state
tcp 0 0 XX.XX.xx.83.9999 . LISTEN -> socket is also in listen state.
```

how can be it in both LISTEN/ESTAB

Answer (score 1):

A single socket cannot both listen and be established. And this is not what you are seeing.

These are two separate sockets, not the same socket. Both sockets are bound to the same local IP and port. But one is connected to a peer (i.e. connection established) while the other is listening for new connections.